# SQL Syntax for default constraint in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to add a default constraint to a existing table. So i use this SQL query. Is there any wrong with this? It generates a error message. Please can anyone give me the correct syntax or tell me what is the error. I have a book and according to its syntax this is correct.

`ALTER TABLE dbo.customer

 ADD CONSTRAINT df_contactname DEFAULT 'Unknown'

 FOR contactname`

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): Syntax error.

Comment: Try putting brackets around 'Unknown'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are trying to add a default value for a column, this would be the correct syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.customer ALTER COLUMN contactname SET DEFAULT 'Unknown'
```

Comment: This doesn't provide the constraint name df_contactname though

Comment: @Clayton: it's not a constraint, it's a default. Defaults have no name.

Comment: @Denis Which means then i cant add a name?

Comment: @jkaushalya: yes. Names are for check/fkey/pkey/unique/etc. constraints. Not defaults.

Comment: Peas and oranges. The question is about MySQL but the quoted code is more of a SQL Server style of deal.